# SELECT query based on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

We have three tables in a **MySQL** Database -

1. Company
2. Employee
3. Address

Company has Employees. Employees have Address. [Note they can have multiple addresses]

Please take a look at the image below for a general idea of the structure

[image: DB Structure]

We have two conditions here -

1.Get all companies whose employee(s) have at least one address listed in the Address table.

Example Query Result should contain the following companies -

Microsoft, Google, IBM

---

2.Get all companies whose employees have no address listed in the Address table.

Example Query Result should contain the following companies -

Yahoo

We have currently written this query which seems to be working for this particular condition-

```
SELECT
  company_id,
  companies.company_name,
FROM companies
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employees    ON employees.company_id = companies.company_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses    ON address.employee_id = employees.employee_id AND address_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE address_id IS  NULL GROUP BY companies.company_id;
```

---

Is there a way to fetch these result using a **single query** to the database without the use of Stored Procedures? It should add a column to the result set (0 or 1) depending on whether a companies employee has an address listed.

Comment: Ahem. You give us a single query which seems to be working, and then you ask how to do it?

Comment: stored procedure? Why would you need that?

Comment: [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c264/9). Group by company and check if the count of related addresses is greater than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Get all companies whose employee(s) have at least one address listed in the Address table.

2.Get all companies whose employees have no address listed in the Address table.

Is there a way to fetch these result using a single query to the database without the use of Stored Procedures?

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM companies
```

---

Updated answer:

```
Select c.[company_id],c.[company_name], CASE WHEN count(a.address_id)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as [flag] from Company c
left join Employee e on e.[company_id] = c.[company_id]
left join Address a on a.[employee_id] = e.[employee_id]
group by c.[ID],c.[company_name]
```

give me result:

```
ID  NAME    FLAG
2   Google  1
3   IBM 1
1   Microsoft   1
4   Yahoo   0
```

sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4163a/3

update: sorry, sqlfiddle for MSSQL. This is fo mysql:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18d09/1

Answer (score 2):

I would just add another column to your existing query and remove your test for IS NULL on the address.  You would get all companies, and a column (flag) indicating if it has no addresses on file.

```
SELECT
      company_id,
      companies.company_name,
      MAX( CASE WHEN address.address_id IS NULL then 1 else 0 end ) as NoAddressOnFile
   FROM 
      companies
         LEFT OUTER JOIN employees
            ON companies.company_id = employees.company_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses    
               ON employees.employee_id = address.employee_id
   GROUP BY
      companies.company_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'UNION' to join two or more queries into single query.

Btw. from your conditions it appears, that you actually want all companies.